# Xamarin Forms Wrestling with Layout cycle detected. Layout could not complete

Tags: listview, exception, xamarin.forms

I have spent a day and a half now wrestling with this. I know there are lots of similar threads out there. I get it: the general problem is that changing X changes Y, and changing Y changes X, and the result is an infinite loop. I just don't see the loop here. If some of of this code does not make sense it is because so much has been commented out in trying to find the problem. Those Height and Width Requests and ScrollBar=Never were added based on some of the suggestions on similar threads. (They did not help.)

In [UWP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Windows_Platform), dragging the border to change the width (but not the height) of the Window causes the subject crash. In Android, changing the orientation causes a long delay followed by "UI is not responding," so I assume that is the same issue.

Further, if I change the limit on the CodeTable initialization loop from 120 to 110 the problem goes away. (I have not bothered to find the exact boundary.)

Any thoughts?

```csharp
public class CodeTableViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<CodeTableRow> CodeTable { get; set; }
    public CodeTableViewModel()
    {
        CodeTable = new ObservableCollection<CodeTableRow>() {};

        for (int c = 0; c <= 120; c++)
            CodeTable.Add(new CodeTableRow(c));
    }

    private CodeTableRow codeTableRow;
    public CodeTableRow CodeTableRow
    {
        get => codeTableRow;
        //set => SetProperty(ref codeTableRow, value);
    }
}
```

```csharp
public class CodeTableRow : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    int codePoint;

    public CodeTableRow(int point)
    {
        codePoint = point;
    }

    public string Decimal
    {
        get
        {
            return codePoint.ToString("D");
        }
    }
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:models="clr-namespace:RefCard.Models"
             x:Class="RefCard.Views.CodeTablePage"
             Title="Code Table"
             BackgroundColor="Khaki">

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <!-- StackLayout HeightRequest="400" WidthRequest="400" -->
        <Grid RowDefinitions="30, *" >
            <ListView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding CodeTable}" Margin="0, 0, 0, 0"
                      x:Name="ListViewCodeTable" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never"  >
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <!-- DataTemplate -->
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:CodeTableRow" >
                        <ViewCell Height="20" >
                            <Grid BackgroundColor="Khaki" >
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Label Grid.Column="0" Text ="{Binding Decimal, Mode=OneWay}"   />
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

```
adasd
```

Comment: Could u draw some wireframe to explain what you're achieving and is there any size calculation in your original code?

Comment: Try to leave the ListView without any parent element to see if "120 rows" is working.

Comment: What I am achieving with this example makes no sense. There used to be a whole app here but I have pared it and pared it trying to get to the essence of the exception. There is almost no code left in the application other than what is posted. The example is what it is and it fails.

Comment: Specifically, no, there is no "sizing" of any sort whatsoever in any of the code. There is almost no code other than what I posted.

Comment: @Shaw I eliminated the Grid that is the parent of the ListView and it still fails the same way (with 120 rows). My original implementation used a StackLayout rather than a Grid. Going to a Grid was one of my many, many attempts at solving this problem. Thanks -- good thought.

Comment: @Shaw just for laughs I ALSO got rid of the Grid that is a child of the ListView. The Label is now directly the child of the ListView. And it still fails the same way. It has something to do with Labels! I just made the Label into a Button and it no longer fails. I don't think that is a workable solution, but it is a clue.